# GCP DNS Zone with Shared VPC - No Networks Available

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

I have host project A which has a couple DNS forwarder zones configured. One of those zones is called example.com. I have a shared VPC set up between host project A and service project B. I want hosts in service project B to be able to resolve unqualified DNS lookups for the example.com zone. So it needs c.project-b.internal added to resolv.conf somehow.

To do this, I assume I need to either add a peering or forwarding zone for example.com in service project B. The problem with this however is that when doing either option, I have no networks to choose from when creating the zone so it's a useless zone. Under "Your private zone will be visible to the selected networks", the network list is always empty in the service project.

I don't want to add this entry to my /etc/resolv.conf file through host scripts or anything like that. I want this to be automatic at the project level.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: DHCP controls options such as hostname, domain, etc unless your clients are running on Windows. For Linux, you must manage your DHCP server or manually configure items such via /etc/hosts. FYI: do not cross post via multiple aliases.